# Python: Comparing dictionary key with string

Tags: python, string, dictionary, comparison

I'm trying to compare the key in a dictionary with a string in Python but I can't find any way of doing this. Let's say I have:

```
dict = {"a" : 1, "b" : 2}
```

And I want to compare the key of the first index in the dictionary (which is "a") with with a string. So something like:

```
if ´Dictionary key´ == "a":
    return True
else:
    return False
```

Is there a way of doing this? Appreciate all the help I can get.

Comment: dict doesn't have indexes. It have keys and values

Comment: Dictionaries aren't ordered data structures, there is no "first index". `'a' in dict` (that's a bad name, by the way, as it shadows the built-in) would tell you if it's a key at all. Also notice you can just `return <boolean_expression>`.

Comment: `print("a" in dict.keys())` ?

Comment: @Rakesh don't use `x in d.keys()`, it is at best redundant (in python 3) because you can just do `x in d`, at worse, in Python 2 it materializes a new list, and changes a constant-time hash-based lookup to a O(N) linear search.... but yes to the point you are making.

Comment: Python `dict` objects do not have indices, they have *keys*. Python `dict` objects are not javascript Objects.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python dictionnaries have **keys** and **values** accessed using those **keys**.

You can access the keys as follows, your dict key will be stored in the `key` variable:

```
my_dict = {"a" : 1, "b" : 2}
for key in my_dict:
    print(key)
```

This will print:

```
a
b
```

---

You can then do any comparisons you want:

```
my_dict = {"a" : 1, "b" : 2}
for key in my_dict:
    if key == "a":
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

which can be improved to:

```
my_dict = {"a" : 1, "b" : 2}
print("a" in my_dict.keys())
```

---

You can then access the values for each key in your dict as follows:

```
my_dict = {"a" : 1, "b" : 2}
for key in my_dict:
    print(my_dict[key])
```

This will print:

```
1
2
```

---

I suggest you read more about dictionaries from the official Python documentation: https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Comment: the last five lines can just be replaced with `return "a" in my_dict`

Comment: @Ev.Kounis Yes obviously, but I'm just using OP's code not to confuse him, I'll add your suggestion in an edit

Comment: @Ev.Kounis it would be `print "a" in my_dict.keys()`

Answer (score 1):

```
result = True if "a" in dict.keys() else False
return result
```

For the example in your question, `result` will be `True`.

If you want to go through each keys, indexes won't help because dictionaries in Python cannot be instead. You can do the following instead:

```
for key in dict.keys():
    #do something with key
```